# Make all bones Euler Rotation?

Tags: animation, armature

Is there a quick way to make all bones in a rig use Euler Rotation rather than Quaternions?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Select the bones to switch and press [CTRL] + [R]. Select the preferred rotation mode.

Comment: It seems the old method that a lot of people suggest of Alt clicking properties to edit all selected doesn't work any more in 2.80. This works though 

Comment: This doesn't work for me in 2.91.0 -- It just starts rotating the bones, there's nothing to pick the preferred rotation mode.

Comment: In Blender 3.6, Ctrl+R rolls the bones, as opposed to R which rotates freely.

Answer (score 5):

Run this script with rig object selected in in pose (or object) mode, changes all rotations to 'XYZ' euler.  Change the order to suit.

```
import bpy
order = 'XYZ'
context = bpy.context
rig_object = context.active_object
for pb in rig_object.pose.bones:
    pb.rotation_mode = order
```

If you have an action check out [this answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/49484/converting-quaternions-to-euler-in-the-graph-editor/49493)

Comment: the only working solution, always coding is best

Comment: It works and doesn't mess up my pose like `Ctrl+R` did.

Answer (score 4):

In *Pose Mode*, select all bones, hold <kbd>Alt</kbd> (Windows) or <kbd>Command</kbd> (Mac) and in *Transform* side panel switch from *Quaternion* to *Euler*.

Comment: Pressing alt or command on their own doesn't do anything.

Comment: If you set a function (like switching a bone rot from quaternion to euler), it will be performed on the active object (last selected). If you do the same holding down the Alt key, it will be performed on all selected object. This works for a lot of functions in Blender. Just be aware that one of the object has to be active for all functions to work (depending on the selection method it can happen that all objects are selected, but none of them is active).

Comment: Does not work in 2.82